# Visual Studio setting to prompt loading symbols when not found

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2022

Let us assume the following code:

```
OuterMethod(InnerMethod())
```

`InnerMethod` is located in the current assembly that I am debugging so I can step into that. `OuterMethod` is located in another assembly that has been installed as a nuget package without symbols. I would also like to step into that. When I used to try that in VS2017 I would be met with a page asking me to load the symbols for that assembly, however in VS2022 this no longer happens and the debugger just steps over `OuterMethod`. How do I get VS to prompt me to locate the symbols for that assembly? Is there a setting somewhere? I am certainly not interested in disabling "Enable Just My Code" - this is not what I want and I remember being able to do this without disabling this setting.